# Removing or adding a class to a column in Datatables only changes the first page

Tags: css, refresh, reload, datatables-1.10

I have the following function to add and remove a class from a column:

```
$('.iconGroup').on('change',function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('img.avatarIcons').removeClass("grayOut");
        useGroupIcons = true;
    } else {
        $('img.avatarIcons').addClass("grayOut");
        useGroupIcons = false;
    }

    $.post("/icons", {
        iconType: 'groups',
        useIcons: useGroupIcons

    }, function (data) {
        window.location = data.redirect
    });
});
```

This is only updating the class for the column on the first page. When I change pages the icons have the same class as the original.

Comment: Can you share more code / info? What do you mean by changing pages? After navigate away to a different html page the classes are not updated?

Comment: Changing pages on the datatable. If I have my datatable showing 10 items per page it only updates the first 10 items, when I move to the following 10 items (page 2), the icons show up with the same way they were originally.

Comment: The next 10 items (from page 2) are available in the DOM when you perform the change on 'iconGroup'?

Comment: Yes, the entire table has 27 items and all the items are created in HTML through a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the page will be redrawn. The best bet is to put your code in a DataTables' [draw](https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw) event, that way whenever it's drawn, it will get your changes.